# Transistor as a switch for 3A collector current

Tags: transistors, switches, raspberry-pi, attiny

I am using:

- ATtiny10 w/ 10Ohm Resistor in series to drive Base of transistor
- Transistor is [ZTX688B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ZTX688B-91843.pdf)
- Vcc is 5V and 3A source
- Load is a Raspberry Pi connected to Collector

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHRGFB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ATtiny is programmed to turn on the Base for 10 seconds and then turn it off for 5 seconds. When I run the circuit it turns on briefly but only manages to 100-200mA (not enough to fully turn on the Pi. How can I make this work? The transistor is rated to handle 3A and up to 12V.

NOTE: I am also open to suggestions of replacing parts. I just need to control the Pis power supply with a MCU.

Comment: Where did  you get the ZTX688B from?

Comment: It is from Mouser. I added a hyperlink to the datasheet

Comment: What is the voltage at PB0, at the transistor's base, and at the transistor's collector?

Comment: @SChand A few things stand out to me about that BJT. (1) It's in a TO-92 package and they claim \$175\:\frac{^\circ\text{C}}{\text{W}}\$, which is close to other TO-92 packaged BJTs with \$200\:\frac{^\circ\text{C}}{\text{W}}\$. All of the specs for \$\beta\$ are in pulsed circumstances with less than 2% duty cycle. For example, \$\beta=400\$ at \$I_\text{C}=3\:\text{A}\$ also says \$V_\text{CE}=2\:\text{V}\$ so not saturated and running at over \$6\:\text{W}\$. In short, you need to think about how this device would work in your case -- not a pulsed case. Be careful.

Comment: Are you sure PB0 is set to be a push-pull output? That's a plausible current from the pullup resistor given the very high hFE of that part.

Comment: @SChand: I've edited in a neater version of your schematic. Note that this can be clearly read from left to right with current, generally, flowing top to bottom.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The PB0 is setup as an output. Not sure what is meant by push-pull but I set up DDRB and PORTB accordingly.

Comment: @Transistor Thank you for that schematic update.

Comment: @jonk Are you saying that I don't have enough voltage to properly run a Raspberry Pi? Since Vce is 2v? Did I select an insufficient part?

Comment: @SChand I'm just worried that you plan to use a part with the expectation that it can handle \$3\:\text{A}\$, continuously, when the specifications specifically say that the testing is done with a duty cycle of 2% (you want 100%, I think) and for a very short pulse width. Not to mention that they brag about a high \$\beta\$ but you can't use that value for considering the base current you will need. That TO-92 cannot handle much continuous dissipation. I am not sure you realize the implications. But maybe I don't know your use well. So it could go either way. I am just worried.

Comment: @jonk I actually need it to handle 3A continuously for very long (days/weeks) periods of time. I guess I am not looking at the right specs. Do you know of something that can handle this current continuously? If not, is there a spec I should look at when selecting this part? A MOSFET was suggested but I have not used one before nor do I know what spec to look at when selecting a new part

Comment: @SChand NFETs are recommended largely because the current you want is a kind of sweet spot for NFETs. At those currents, a BJT needs a lot of recombination current to act as a switch. You can do that with a couple of BJTs and some resistors. But usually people prefer to just go with the NFET. Me? NFETs are >10X the cost of the BJTs I buy (often 100X.) And I have a lot more of them floating around here. So I usually make the BJT work, anyway. But you may want to consider an NFET for this (trivial to use, so it's not even worth writing about it.) If you want a BJT design, I'll offer one.

Comment: @jonk I would appreciate a BJT design since I prefer using the BJT as I ordered 10 of them already. I am currently trying an S8850 Transistor with the base controlled by ATtiny10 and from a 5V source to S8850 Collector I have 2k Resistor with a jumper to the Base of the ZTX688B hoping to generate enough current to drive the Pi. It seems to work very briefly before failing and always remaining ON instead of the programmed 10 seconds on 5 seconds off cycle.

Comment: @SChand The S8850 is a PNP. Do you have the matching S8050, as well? Or are you without any NPNs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93211/discussion-between-schand-and-jonk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your schematic, the current flowing from PB0 to T1's base-emitter junction is \$I_B = (5V - 0.6V) / 10\Omega = 440mA\$, which is extremely high for a MCU-pin's drive capability. Thus PB0 may limit the output *(I'm not sure, but I hope)*.

To saturate the transistor, a base current of \$I_{Bs} = \frac{I_C}{ (\beta_{min}/10)}\$ 
is sufficient *(I cannot prove this, but this comes from my experiences)*. From your circuit, this base current is 3000mA / (400/10) = 75mA, which is still extremely high for MCU's port/pin.

The most efficient way is to use an N-Channel MOSFET *(with logic-level gate)* instead.

Comment: +1 for MOSFET better here. Lots of info around like http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/.

Comment: _"... 440mA , which is extremely high for a MCU-pin's drive capability."_ - It's definitely outside the attiny10's absolute maximum rating of 40mA. Although attiny I/O pins are in my experience relatively forgiving for such abuse, it's not impossible he killed the pin.

Comment: Even if the micro could supply that much, it would have to come from the micro's power supply, which may not be sufficient.  The OP needs a Darlington pair, a super beta transistor, or a logic-level FET designed for the operating voltage of the microprocessor.

Comment: Would I be able to use a 2nd Transistor driven by the ATtiny PB0 to provide the adequate current for the B gate? I hope that makes sense

Comment: @SChand I would never use BJTs for switching such high currents. Why not use a MOSFET instead? For example, 2N7000 can be a direct replacement to ZTX688B. It's a very common, easy to find and cheap MOSFET.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I actually didn't realize MOSFET was a better fit for this project. I will order a MOSFET and am also trying to get a Darlington Pair design working as well for this project.